# angular-strap popover doesn't work in ie8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I have added angular-strap popover to my web-app project, all functions work well in chrome, but when I open my website in IE8, the popover function failed.

I can make sure the angular-strap popover can work in IE8 because I open the angular-strap official website in ie8 (http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/), the popover function works well.

I don't know what is wrong with my code.

```
<a href="#" data-placement="bottom" data-template="add-resource.tpl.html"
  bs-popover="agentItem">Specify a resource</a>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="add-resource.tpl.html">
          <div class="popover">
            <div class="arrow"></div>   
            <span class="annotation">(seprate multipile resources with commas)</span>
            <div>
                <input type="text" ng-model="newResources" class="popover-input">
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="popover-btn" ng-click="addResource(newResources,agentItem);newResources='';$hide()">Add
                    Resource</button>
                <button class="popover-btn" ng-click="$hide()">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </script>
        <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular-strap/angular-strap.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular-strap/angular-strap.tpl.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

I use **cached template id** as my template. I'm not sure whether this caused my problem.

Is there anyone that knows how to make angular-strap work in IE8?

Comment: Did't !! https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/210

Comment: @RameshRajendran i still didn't understand, can you give me more detail?